# Using VIM, how do I remap directional keys from right hand to left hand?

Tags: vim, right-to-left

This is the best solution I've seen so far:

```
" Map Right Directionals to Left Commands
noremap s h
noremap d k
noremap f j
noremap g l

" Map Left Commands to Right Directionals
noremap h s
noremap k d
noremap j f
noremap l g
```

However, when actually using this mapping, it requires a double-press on the 's' and 'g' keys when switching from left to right.

Is there a better way to re-map these keys to work 100% correctly without the need to double-press keys?

Comment: As the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) mentions: Please, do not [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/408640/using-vim-how-do-i-remap-directional-keys-from-right-hand-to-left-hand).

Comment: Are you trying to support both sets of keys simultaneously in vim?

Comment: How are you defining "simultaneously"?  If you mean swapping the functionality of the left and right home keys, then yes.  I've also tried `nnoremap`, but that doesn't work.  The best solution so far for me has been to use `d` and `f` for up and down, and `h` and `l` for left and right.

Comment: @Masao Kitamura : it works for me perfectly. I am unlsing vim 7.2 in Linux.